# Is the cc recipients in a received email a Python list? (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I am trying to pull the cc'ed email addresses from received email. I am working in the development server.

[The tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html) says that "cc contains a list of the cc recipients." But it seems that `message.cc` returns a string. I am just using the code I copied from the cookbook:

```
class ReceiveEmail(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        logging.info("Received email from %s" % message.sender)
        plaintext = message.bodies(content_type='text/plain')
        for text in plaintext:
            txtmsg = ""
            txtmsg = text[1].decode()
            logging.info("Body is %s" % txtmsg)
            logging.info("CC email is %s" % message.cc)
```

So if I have 1 cc, the log shows:

`CC email is cc12@example.com`

If there are more than 1:

`CC email is cc12@example.com, cc13@example.com`

To get the first email "cc12@example.com", I tried:

```
logging.info("CC email is %s" % message.cc[0])
```

but this gives:

`CC email is c`

so the result is treated as a string.

When I try

logging.info("CC email is %s" % list(message.cc)

I get

```
['c', 'c', '1', '2', '@', 'e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', ',', ' ', 'c', 'c', '1', '3', '@', 'e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', ',', ' ', 'c', 'c', '1', '4', '@', 'e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm'
```

Again, it appears that `message.cc` returns string not list.

Do I need to use regex to get the emails? Any suggestions about what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
cc_list = message.cc.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

**cc**

A recipient's email address (a string) or a list of email addresses to appear on the Cc: line in the message header.

[Message Fields](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields.html)

cc is a string

message.cc.split(", ")[0] is "cc12@example.com" that you want.

Comment: Thanks. The way I read this sentence from the tutorial is that an email address is a string but the cc field is a "list". Apparently, they don't mean a Python list.